# How to split AngularJS application into smaller modules and handle routing correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**What would be the best way to split AngularJS application into smaller pieces/module?** For example if I have a blog post and commenting enabled for that, I think I could break it down to modules like "posts" and "comments"(?) (maybe not the best example, but the idea is to split the application logic into separate modules rather than building a huge one-module-app).

I've tried to bootstrap both modules in the separate DOM nodes and use routing in both of the modules accordingly. There are few problems:

- As a "single-page" application I'm bootstrapping comments module to be used even on the front page even though it's not used there.
- Since I'm not able to use multiple ng-views inside ng-app, I'm forced to write all the wrappers for my modules in the index.html view and bootstrap them? Should it be like that? Seems a bit wrong. How/where should I bootstrap those?
- Are there any tips for the routing? Should I spread those in the modules or should I combine them all together somehow? (creating one "blog" module to include "posts" and "comments" modules as dependencies would still make it hard to define for example the "/post/:id" routing..?)

index.html

```html
<div class="post"><ng-view></ng-view></div>
<div class="comments"><ng-view></ng-view></div>
```

javascript.js

```js
angular.module('posts', []).config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        'template': 'Showing all the posts',
        'controller': 'postCtrl
    })
    .when('/post/:id', {
        'template': 'Showing post :id',
        'controller': 'postCtrl
    });
}]);

angular.module('comments', []).config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/post/:id', {
        'template': 'Showing post :id comments',
        'controller': 'CommentsCtrl'
    });
}]);

angular.bootstrap($('.post'), ['posts']);
angular.bootstrap($('.comments'), ['comments']);
```

Answer (score 20):

I would divide the app in "view modules" and these sub modules.

Then I use the $routeProvider to switch between the views. I define the different routing config in each module.

If I need further submodules, I load these with ng-include.

```
/* App Module */

angular.module('MyApp', ['MyApp.home', 'MyApp.blog'])
.config( function myAppConfig ( $routeProvider ) {
    'use strict';
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
});


/* home Module */

angular.module('MyApp.home', [])
.config(['$routeProvider', function config( $routeProvider ) {
  $routeProvider.when('/home', {
    controller: 'HomeController',
    template: '<p>This is my Home</p>'
  });
}]);
```

I created a little repository on [github](https://github.com/sgebhardt/ng-module-boilerplate) to explain this.

Comment: Thanks for answering! So basically the idea is to build one main app module that's bootstrapped and other "view modules" as dependencies for that. Spreading the routing information into these modules and instead of relying on multiple ng-views and bootstrapping different modules one by one, this solution relies heavily on ng-include. This wouldn't take an advantage of the ng-view and $routeProviders controller & template handling that much, but makes modules more freely used across the application (different places/routes/views..) If I understood correctly?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. IMHO AngularJS dosn't support multiple ng-view directives out of the box.
If you need multiple ng-view directives, look at this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/ayG1hCUOfX0

Comment: this is a great pattern, I wonder if there is a way to define a module using the simplified commonjs wrapper..

Answer (score 6):

You can define routes in the submodules:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'app.moduleX'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  });

  //Handle all exceptions
  $routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
  });
})

angular.module('app.moduleX', []).config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/settings', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/settings.html',
    controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
  });
})
```

I also wrote [a blog post](http://blog.fragaria.cz/2014/08/modular-menu-with-angularjs.html) about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

We're doing something similar with a portal app and sub-apps. A few things we've discovered:

1. Only one "app" can have routes and routeParams. Because of this, if the "sub-app" needs access to the $routeParams, you either have to go "old school" for URL parsing, or use an event service.
2. Speaking of events, there is no Angular service for the apps to communicate, so you'll need to roll your own event service talking to root scope for both apps and inject it into both apps.
3. I can't see where we used ng-view for the "sub-app". Apparently bootstrapping directly to an element works similarly.
4. Because only one app can have routes, the apps should be bootstrapped in order. So something like this:

   ```
   $( function () {

       $.when(angular.bootstrap($('.post'), ['posts'])).done( function() {
           console.log('POSTS: bootstrapped');

           //Manually add the controller to the comments element. (May or may not be  
           //necessary, but we were doing something that required it to work.)
           $('.comments').attr('ng-controller', 'CommentsCtrl');

           $.when(angular.bootstrap($('.comments'), ['comments'])).done( function() {
               console.log('COMMENTS: bootstrapped');
           });

       });
   });
   ```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I think I succeeded to access $routeParams from a "sub-app", but do you mean for clarity's sake you keep all the routes inside one main application also? (Or did I just misunderstood what you meant..) Good point about the event service, I think that's something I might need to implement too. Also do you mean you're not using multiple ng-views but rather use ng-include or something?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can use **"ui-router"** routing module.

Here is good tutorial for this http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-ui-router.html