# angular sub module route

Tags: angularjs, module, ngroute

I have a:

- main module : kp
- sub module : kp.venue

**I want kp.venue to have it's own "route" definitions (for all paths relative to that module).**
This is what I am trying to achieve in the code bellow.
**Can anyone explain me why it doesn't work?**

*I followed the technique presented in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15301427/971008*

```
(function () {
'use strict';
    angular.module('kp.venue', [])

    .config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when("/venue", {
                template : "<p>This is the venue module</p>",
                controller: "VenueCtrl"
            });
        }
    ])

    .controller('VenueCtrl', ['$scope',
        function($scope){
            console.log("VenueController");
        }
    ]);

    angular.module('kp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'kp.venue'])

    .config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
        function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true, requireBase:false});
        $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                template: "<p>main app</p>",
                controller: "MainController"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
        }
    ]);

    //Load controller
    angular.module('kp')

    .controller('MainController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
            $scope.test = "Testing...";
        }
    ]);
}());
```

*Note that I have already tried to move "kp.venue" bellow the definition of "kp" module to be sure that it was not a problem related to things not being loaded in the right order.*

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: @Chandermani : when browsing to http://localhost:8888/venue, I get "Cannot GET /venue" in the view, but no console error

Comment: Are you talking about in network log. If yes the view html is not available.

Comment: @Chandermani no sorry, I am talking about the actual output in the browser window : "Cannot GET /venue". I would expect to see the content of template : "<p>This is the venue module</p>"

Comment: In html5mode, how you land on the view has an impact. if you directly type in the browser a request is made to the server and in that case you should  have server side url rewrite working.

Comment: @Chandermani Ok, this is weird : When I browse to http://localhost:8888/#venue the template is displayed and the url gets rewritten without the hash http://localhost:8888/venue. But if I access the URL without the hash, it fails to load the template into my page and I get the "Cannot GET /venue". So I guess the issue is somehow related to the fact that I enabled pushstate
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true, requireBase:false});

Comment: @Chandermani Ok, I better understand the problem then. I have a simple "connect" server running in the background. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you do a full page refresh, it is not intercepted by Angular, but the request goes to server. Hence the endpoint should be valid and return the same index page content irrespective of the url requested