# routing sub-modules in angular

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

## how to write different modules with their own routing?

i have an angular app and it has different modules.i am going to write for each of them, specific route file, but i got this error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/unpr?p0=routeServiceProvider%20%3C-%20routeService

it is my code :

sample.module.js

```
angular.module('app.sample', []);
```

sample.route.js

```
angular
.module('app.sample')
.run(appRun);

  /* @ngInject */
  function appRun (routeService) {
     routeService.configureRoutes(getRoutes());
  }

 function getRoutes () {
    return [ {
       url: '/sample',
       config: {
          templateUrl: 'sample.html'
       }
     }
    ];
}
```

i already add ngRoute and inject these files in `index.html` file

Comment: what is `routeService`?

Comment: i don't know what's that exactly, i just copy it from other app that works fine @Claies

Comment: well it is a service that must be defined somewhere, but doesn't seem to exist in your project.  it's *not* part of `ng-route`.

Comment: what is the correct way to route without this service? @Claies

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to ask.  This doesn't look anything at all like code that would be used with `ng-route`, and you mention that you just copied it from some other app, but you didn't copy the service that this code relies on.  If you want to use `ng-route`, have you tried using the code from the official documentation?  or finding this service in the "working" app and copying it into your new app?

Comment: i try writing code that works fine, what is the correct way to have sub-routes for each module?@Claies

Comment: it *seems like* the correct way is to implement a service which takes the route and passes it to the route provider for the main app module.  It also seems like that's what this `routeService` is designed to do;  If you are asking for someone to rewrite this service for you, that's way too broad of a request.

Comment: i saw that working app before and i think there is a way to write routers in each module, so all of routes should be define in main app to work without that service, am i right? @Claies

Comment: Honestly what you are describing here is components, and component routing.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve such project structure, [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) is the best way to go. It is a separate library so you have to include into your project as a dependency.

Here are the snippets that will be useful for your case

dashboard.module.js

```
angular.module('app.dashboard', ['ui.router']);
```

dashboard.router.js

```
    angular.module('app.dashboard')
        .config(routerConfig);

    routerConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
    function routerConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('state1', {
                url: '/state1',
                templateUrl: 'url/to/state1.html',
                controller: function () {
                    // controller code here
                }
            })
            .state('state2', {
                url: '/state2',
                templateUrl: 'url/to/state2.html',
                controller: function () {
                    // controller code here
                }
            });
    }
```

sample.module.js

```
angular.module('app.sample', ['ui.router']);
```

sample.router.js

```
angular.module('app.sample')
        .config(routerConfig);

    routerConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
    function routerConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('state3', {
                url: '/state3',
                templateUrl: 'url/to/state3.html',
                controller: function () {
                    // controller code here
                }
            })
            .state('state4', {
                url: '/state4',
                templateUrl: 'url/to/state4.html',
                controller: function () {
                    // controller code here
                }
            });
    }
```

Lastly, `app.module` that connects all these modules

app.module.js

```
angular.module('app', [
    /*
     * sub-modules
     */
    'app.dashboard',
    'app.sample'
]);
```

To sum up, you have two independent sub-modules (`app.dashboard` and `app.sample`) with their own routing logic and one module (`app`) that wraps them into one angular application.

`$stateProvider`, service provided by `ui.router`, is used for registering states.

**Additional info**

Since your application is modular, you are probably going to need nested routing which is greatly supported by `ui.router`. Read [docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/) to get more information on nested states.

**Update**

However, if you still want to stick with ngRoute, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253500/angular-sub-module-route?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294321/how-to-split-angularjs-application-into-smaller-modules-and-handle-routing-corre/15301427#15301427) clearly explain how to achieve the same result.